# Laravel - Redirect to route with optional parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have this route:

```
Route::get('search/{state?}/{city?}/{brand?}/{model?}', array('as'=>'search-cars'), function($a=false, $b=false, $c=false, $d=false) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

How can I send parameters to the route above from my controller? I've tried:

```
public function postHomeSearch() {
    $state= (Input::get('state')) ? Input::get('state') : null;
    $city = (Input::get('city')) ? Input::get('city') : null;
    $brand= (Input::get('brand')) ? Input::get('brand') : null;
    $model= (Input::get('model')) ? Input::get('model') : null;

    $data = array(
        'state' => $state,
        'city'  => $city,
        'brand'  => $make,
        'model' => $model,
    );

    return Redirect::route('search-cars',$data);  // <---- HERE
}
```

Please notice that some parameters can be null if they're not selected

Comment: Your code just seems good. Have you tried not including the parameter on the array if it is null? Also, match the name of the parameters on the function signature.

Comment: What's not working about this solution?

Comment: @facundofarias and lukasgeiter... I get this URL when calling postHomeSearch() **http://localhost/laravel/App/public/search///California///All** -- notice the triple **///**

Comment: Looks to me like some `null` values are the problem. What URL do you expect if only the `brand` is set?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I expect **localhost/laravel/App/public/search/brandName** or if for expample _city_ is also set then **localhost/laravel/App/public/search/brandName/City**

Comment: I have also tried `false` instead of `null` but I keep getting the same result :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like the problem are `null` values. You can remove those using `array_filter` and then pass the data to the redirect function not as associative array but just as values (so they will be resolved in order and not by parameter name)

```
$data = Input::only('state', 'city', 'brand', 'model');
$data = array_filter($data); // remove falsy values
$data = array_values($data); // remove keys
return Redirect::route('search-cars', $data);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. I also suggest you change the parameter names in your route to `{a?}/{b?}`. It will make it clearer that `{state?}` doesn't actually have to be the state...